# После деплоя React-приложения на gh-pages не выводятся изображения. На localhost все работает

Tags: reactjs, изображения

Изображения лежат d:\Phones\public\media\img.jpg.

Компоненты, указывающие путь к изображениям, лежат на d:\Phones\src\components\component.js

Вызов изображений из одного из компонентов следующий:

```
    import React from "react";
    export default ({ user, update, index}) => {
     return (
      <tr onClick={() => update({active: index})}>
       <td><img src={`../../media/${user.image}.jpg`} alt="" className="user-image" /></td>
       <td>{user.name}</td>
       <td>{user.phone}</td>
      </tr>
     );
    }
```

Помогите правильно вызвать изображения, чтобы они отображались после деплоя на gh-pages.

Comment: Попробуйте указать base href='/': https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

И покажите как ссылка на изображение на проде выглядит.

Answer (score 0):

суть в том, что Вы указывали относительный путь для изображения в проекте, который на стадии разработки и еще не собран. после сборки проекта структура файлов, конечно же, меняется, но Ваши пути для изображений остаются те же.

для этого указывайте `src` изображения как импортируемый модуль, например:

```
<img
    src={require(`../../media/${user.image}.jpg`)}
    alt=""
    className="user-image"
/>
```